# How to open jupyter notebook with spaces in file name in command prompt?

Tags: cmd, jupyter-notebook

I use :  jupyter notebook file_name.ipynb.
But how to open file with spaces in it's name. For example :
filename is : " ABC XYZ .ipynb"

jupyter notebook ABC XYZ .ipynb , don't work.

Comment: Use `jupyter notebook "ABC XYZ .ipynb"`. This is a Super User question and not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

escape special characters with a backslash: 
`ABC\ XYZ.ipynb`

Answer (score 0):

Your Question has answer itself. Try this way `jupyter notebook "ABC XYZ.ipynb"`